# Why Java file doesn't find the Drawable xml file in android studio?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-studio, android-drawable

I am making an alarm clock. In one of my java file I have to find an drawable file like this: `layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.view_touch_selector);`
But, it shows error and says **can't resolves symbol view_touch_selector**. I don't know why it's happening although I have that corresponding *view_touch_selector* created.

[image]

UPDATE (after **original android's** answer):

*Can't resolve symbol 'R' error!* The 'R' becomes red in each file.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried cleaning UR project

Comment: You may have erroneously imported android.R or similar, blocking your own.  Or you may have an error in your xml which prevents its compilation to R.java and thus preents detecting this element.

Comment: @Riyana, I noticed your latest update. Can you post your imports in that Java file? I want to check what you're importing, especially something like import com.<whatever>.R. If you use the same package name for all your Java files, then importing com.xxx.R files is not necessary. Similar to what Chris said, I think.  Thanks for mentioning my handle name, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem is that **view_touch_selector** has not been created in the generated **R.java** file.  This is an anomaly (may be common) so you'll have to try one or more of the steps listed below (ordered from easiest/short time to longer). If you execute step 1, then do compile. Then try step 2, then compile, and so on.
From Android Studio, using either File or Menu bar:

1. Select the res/drawable folder from Project tree and select File -> Synchronize.
2. Menu -> Build -> Rebuild Project
3. Menu -> Build -> Clean Project, then build it.
4. File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart
5. Menu Tools -> Android -> Sync Project with Gradle Files

The idea is to make the Studio recompile your xml files correctly; Eclipse has a similar problem.
Finally, if all else fails, rename your package, forcing all the project files to be evaluated. Warning, renaming package is not easy.
I never had to do this for fixing this kind of problem.

> **EDIT**:  R.java file is at few places. The directories listed here is generated by Android Studio. R.java is at
>
> - [project directory]\Application\build\generated\source\r\debug\com\example\android[package
>     name]
>
> There are intermediate files generated by compiler including view_touch_selector.xml:
>
> - [project directory]\Application\build\intermediates\res\debug\drawable
>
> Another file to check, though this is rarely a problem I think, is
>   **workspace.xml**. When you select File -> Synch, workspace.xml is updated. File is at **[project directory].idea**. Again this is using
>   Android Studio.
>
> In workspace.xml, it should include your xml files like:
>
> layout
>   url="file://$PROJECT_DIR$/Application/src/main/res/layout/**view_touch_selector.xml**">
>
> Between R.java and workspace.xml, they should be updated to the latest
>   date/time. And if you don't see the R.java file, then that's a major
>   problem related to directories. You may have to create a new project.

Good luck on this one, Tommy Kwee

Comment: Tommy your answer helps but it didn't solve the problem completely. See my update in post. The symbol 'R' is not resolved. I guess I have to do something with R.java file as others suggest. But i don't fnd that file anywhere in my project. I don't know where does it located.

Comment: @Riyana, Ok now, I am putting my deep investigator hat. This anomaly gives me a chance to post the most complete answer ever to an annoying bug (sorry Google). I updated my answer under the EDIT block in quotes. Let's work on this one. Meantime I need to go away from the computer, forgive me.

Comment: hi Tommy, all this issue is gone. but I have some problem with my alarm clock project. There is some bugs in my project. they are not a lot off course. I and my friend have tried a  lot to solve it. can u help me with that? I will decsribe u more about my problem. In this case can I continue to private chat with u here? is that Ok for you?

Comment: Please post the question or problem at SO first. However I have not done an Alarm clock feature yet.